# When attempting to specify handling of whitespace characters in vim, how does one figure out character-encoding specifiers, and then implement them?

Tags: vim, character-encoding

I'm trying to specify how to display whitespace characters in vim. I've seen a lot of suggestions, and am trying to use this:

```
:set listchars=tab:→\ ,space:·,nbsp:␣,trail:•,eol:¶,precedes:«,extends:»
```

But I'm getting `E474: Invalid argument: listchars=tab:\~F~R\ ,space:·,nbsp:~P,trail:~@,eol:¶,precedes:«,extends:»`. I'm pretty sure the text encoding isn't right (Am I even saying that right?).

I'm guessing I have to cast the character type? Or something? How does one find out what encoding is needed, then how do they specify it correctly in .vimrc?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: With your `vimrc` opened, what is the exact output of `:echo &encoding &fileencoding`?

Comment: utf-8, and utf-8

Answer (score 1):

> How does one find out what encoding is needed, then how do they specify it correctly in .vimrc?

The command is called `:help`. The only command **every** Vim user **must** know.

From `:h 'listchars'`:

> The characters ':' and ',' should not be used.  UTF-8 characters can be used when 'encoding' is "utf-8", otherwise only printable characters are allowed.  All characters must be single width.

So either you're using encoding different from UTF-8, or some outdated Vim version.

Comment: `:echo &encoding` and `:echo &fileencoding` Both returned UTF-8, and my vim version is 8.1 compiled Jun15 2019

Comment: Maybe I have a character that's not single width